# How to speedup large np.add.outer on large matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I originally posted a question about computing logsumexp efficiently found here

[How to efficiently compute logsumexp of upper triangle in a nested loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54031980/how-to-efficiently-compute-logsumexp-of-upper-triangle-in-a-nested-loop?noredirect=1#comment94900728_54031980)

The answer I accepted was

```
import Numpy as np

Wm  = np.array([[1,   2,   3],
                [4,   5,   6],
                [7,   8,   9],
                [10, 11,  12]])

wx  = np.array([1,   2,   3])
wy  = np.array([4,   5,   6])

Wxy = np.array([[5,   6,   7],
                [6,   7,   8],
                [7,   8,   9]])

'''
np.triu_indices = ([0, 0, 1], [1, 2, 2])
Wxy[triu_inds] = [6, 7, 8]
np.logsumexp(Wxy[triu_inds]) = log(exp(6) + exp(7) + exp(8))
'''

for x in range(n-1):
    wx = Wm[x, :]
    for y in range(x+1, n):
        wy = Wm[y, :]
        Wxy = np.add.outer(wx, wy)
        Wxy = Wxy[triu_inds]
        W[x, y] = np.logsumexp(Wxy)

# solution here
W = np.logsumexp(
    np.add.outer(Wm, Wm).swapaxes(1, 2)[(slice(None),)*2 + triu_inds],
    axis=-1  # Perform summation over last axis.
)
W = np.triu(W, k=1)
```

The problem is that this is really slow with large matrices as the problem explodes quickly.  If `Wm`'s dimensions are `m,n` the amount of memory needed grows as `(m*n)**2 * 8` bytes.  I need to run this on matrices larger than `1000x200` but I get memory errors and it's very slow.

Comment: When you post a dataset, you should make sure people can simply copy paste it. Currently one has to insert commas to make it a 2d array and put `np.array()` in front of every line. And what is this `logsumexp`? Where is it defined? I strongly encourage you to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: added the np.array, logsumexp is defined above

Comment: No it is still wrong. The commas are still missing. Do me a favor. Copy paste you whole code in a fresh python terminal and hit execute. Then let me know if it this code in the present form works for you. And no, `logsumexp(Wxy[triu_inds]) = log(exp(6) + exp(7) + exp(8))` is not the definition. You will get `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call`. All the imports are missing.

Comment: Unless readers can see for themselves if your code explodes for large matrices, no one will have an idea what exactly to do. You should also provide the dataset for which it explodes. As I said, copy paste your code in terminal and see if it produces the result

Comment: It's probably much better just to `@jit` or ideally `@njit` your original algorithm (which uses nested for loops rather than constructing a giant outer product) using Numba. A common use case of Numba is in replacing vectorized solutions like this that seem efficient at first but play badly with memory.